# Local development and symlinked shared libraries

Tags: php, apache, composer-php

I tried to setup my local apache docroot as follow for local php  development.

For example, a fragment of the directory structure:

```
- Libs-git (shared lib packages)
-- Wp_Libs (Contains common libraries for wordpress dev)
--- autoload.php
--- composer
--- my-shared-pkg1
--- my-shared-pkg2

- Wp.Sites
-- Wp.Site1
--- wp-libs (Symlink to Wp_Libs above)
--- wp-content/plugins/myplugin-site1

-- Wp.Site2
--- wp-libs (Symlink to Wp_Libs above)
--- wp-content/plugins/myplugin-site2
```

Keeping this structure allows me to easily make changes to shared packages and they will be available for all sites using those without copy and paste them each time.

The problem:

When Wp.Site1 calls include statements defined in functions from the Wp_Libs original libs , I get 404 error as output of includes.

Example code from  (wp-content/plugins/myplugin-site1/plugin.php):

```
include "wp-libs/autoload.php"; //shared composer autoloader

use my/shared/pkg1;

pkg1::show_tpl('filename'); //This statement should include a file relative to the plugin folder (wp-content/plugins/myplugin/tpls/filename.html)
```

Why I get 404 error page as output from include statements? If I check the include path it exists..

Comment: is "follow symlinks" enabled for your directory?

Comment: @ArSeN Yes each site runs as vhost, the config file contains the line `Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks` for each directory

Comment: well then, second guess: are the file permissions properly set? e.g. does the user that apache runs under, also have access to your Wp.Site1 directory and its files?

Comment: @ArSeN Yes _www user has access to all those folders

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try installing the re-used libs as [global](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global). Anyway, the problem doesn't seem to be a composer one, more like configuration issue.

Comment: It definitively seems a problem of paths and include context.. composer setup seems fine, I can access all packages and class libraries from my plugins but when libraries have to load/include something outside their folder "context" and so, something of plugins, giving them the full real path however doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved! The issue was a little programming bug (wrong default values on function parameters in library) which was altering in a way the request handler of the entire site, any inclusion of files was treated as an http request. Now all is working fine.

This question could be marked as resolved.

Thanks you all anyway for the help!